# Laragon - Run multiple projects simultaneously

Tags: laravel, apache, laragon

Is it possible to run two projects simultaneously on different PHP versions?

I've one project which uses 7.4 and another that uses 8.0.

Both of these projects run and communicate to each other however its difficult to switch between each project without changing the php version and restarting apache.

Is there a way to run these together like you can with homestead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish this with the use of virtual host, if you just build virtual hosts for two distinct projects and include the PHP version that each project requires, as shown in the example below.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.x-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```